# c socket read returns -1,but passes the while test strangely?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to complete a web proxy using c socket programming.
when the client press STOP button in the browser, the server returns -1 in read, but
it seems to pass the while test strangely,the code is as following:
(rio_readlineb is a robust read from a buffer rio to user buffer buf)

```
while ((n = rio_readlineb(&rio,buf,MAXLINE)) > 0){
 printf("%d",n)
}
```

since n is greater than zero, how can -1 be printed out?

Extra info (from comments):

- The type of `n` is supposed to be of type `ssize_t`.
- The return type of `rio_readlineb()` is also of type `ssize_t`.

...

- Oops: the problem was that `n` was actually of type `size_t`.

Comment: Type n is probably an unsigned type?

Comment: the type of n is ssize_t,it should be signed type

Comment: And what if you change your test to `!= -1` instead? Also, what does `rio_readlineb` return as a type?

Comment: the return type of rio_readlineb is ssize_t,

Comment: but n is size_t ,there is no warning during compiling,now it's OK.thank u guys

Comment: no diagnostic is required by C for assignment between objects of any arithmetic type.

Answer (score 5):

Check the type of `n` is not of an unsigned integer type. The result of an object of unsigned integer type when checked if greater or equal to 0 is always 1 (true).